# format datetime specific timezone

Tags: javascript, date-formatting, javascript-globalize

I am using globalize to format datetime per locale.

```
var Globalize = require('globalize');
var formatter = Globalize('en-US').dateFormatter();
formatter(new Date());
```

It works great but I was wondering if I can format date for specific timezone. This way, it always formats date in the local machine timezone. 
For example, let's say my machine timezone is PST. Can I use globalize to format date in EST?

Comment: Does the library have documentation on how to set timezones?

Comment: A time zone is not a format, it's (typically) an offset from UTC and can be represented in many different ways. Common are non-standard abbreviations like "EST" and "WAST", military designators like "K" and "Z" and numeric representations like "+05:30".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stolen from [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/6016329/)

This solution works by using the **getTimeOffset()** (which returns the time difference between UTC time and local time, in minutes) function to find the UTC time offset of a given location and changing it to milliseconds, then performing calculations from UTC to return a time for a different time zone.

```
/** 
 * function to calculate local time
 * in a different city
 * given the city's UTC offset
 */
function calcTime(city, offset) {

// create Date object for current location
var d = new Date();

// convert to msec
// add local time zone offset
// get UTC time in msec
var utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

// create new Date object for different city
// using supplied offset
var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

// return time as a string
return "The local time in " + city + " is " + nd.toLocaleString();
}
```

This solution will work, but it's simpler to express timezone in minutes and adjust the UTC minutes.

Please let  me know if this works for you!

Comment: Which doesn't really work if the implementation's *toLocaleString* method includes the time zone, since it will show the host time zone, not the one to which it's been adjusted.

Comment: He could just use a different return method to display time zone though, assuming one exists, right? If that's the case, then I guess this solves half of his problem...

Comment: Yes, it works to that extent though it's much simpler to express the timezone in minutes and adjust the UTC minutes. This seems to expect the timezone to be expressed in decimal hours, e.g. 5.5, whereas they are more commonly expressed in ±hh:hh or ±hhmm format (e.g. +05:30).

Comment: Fair enough, I'll edit my original comment to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

The javascript function `new date()` generates a date/time stamp based off the machine time at the moment that the function was called. So if the function is called by a machine that is in Alaska, it will generate a date/time stamp based on the current time in Alaska at that exact moment.

w3school.com has great references to most coding related items. You can find the answer to your question [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp).

Comment: This does not answer the question and w3schools is not the best reference.

Comment: I'm just starting to get accustomed to Stack Overflow. Can you explain why w3schools isn't considered a good reference? I use them a lot for learning new things.